# center individual item in flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox structure like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="flex-child-1">

        <div class="sub-1">
            sub-item 1
        </div>

        <div class="sub-2">
            sub item 2
        </div>

    </div> //end item 1

    <div class="flex-child-2">
        item 2
    </div> // end item 2

</div> // end container
```

I am looking to vertically center `sub-2` inside of its container: `flex-child-1` (which is itself a flexbox child). Note, I don't want to center `sub-1`.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [flexbox specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/) allows for [absolutely-positioned flex children](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#abspos-items), which enables you to center individual flex items:

**CSS**

```
.flex-child-1 {
    display: flex;
    height: 480px; /* for demo purposes */
    position: relative; /* establish nearest positioned ancestor for abs. positioning */
}

/* for vertical and horizontal centering */
.sub-2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /* relative to nearest positioned ancestor */
    top: 50%; /*  relative to nearest positioned ancestor */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* relative to element's height & width */
}

/* for vertical centering only */
.sub-2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/24tpsvb9/6/